# Framework or Class for a TableView for a train scedule / time table

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, timetable

I wonder if there is a framework or class for creating a train scedule similar to the below screenshot. Of course I know, I can create the table cells myself, but probably there is already a framework available.

Many thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question: I finally did it by creating a custom table cell and drawing rectangles and lines for visualizing the route.